# Incorrect Documentation - You can't create outbound messages for workflow rules on junction objects

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage, junction-object, documentation

In [Workflow Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_rules_considerations.htm&type=5) documentation, Workflow Limitations section, it has been specified that.

> You can't create outbound messages for workflow rules on junction objects.

[image: Incorrect doc]

I have created a junction object `Contact - Financial Account Junction`.

[image: Junction Object]

And Salesforce allows me to define Outbound message on Junction object.

[image: Outbound Msg]

Secondly, in the **Integrating with Outbound Messaging** training course, (which can be opened from this link of Integration Architect resource guide, at Page No. 14.), knowledge check section, it corrects says as follows:

> **Outbound messaging can include junction objects to send data.**

[image: Correct ans]

I would request Salesforce to rectify incorrect documentation in Salesforce Help document.

Comment: Not really a question here. Did you submit feedback?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, I know, but at-least I have documented here, I have posted in twitter taking this reference. Thinking how it will reach to proper person or group

Comment: Have you joined the slack channel yet?

Comment: not yet, I am waiting for the kit

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this has been acknowledged by SFDC themselves in 2012 but no change to documentation since.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BJvIAM